# React Native Redux RTK Query returns null reponse. Similar solution works with Fetch API

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

First, I have implemented my solution with Fetch API which I have tested and it works. Then I came across Redux RTK Query and wanted to give it a try, but I get null as a response:

> LOG  response 
> LOG  null 
> ERROR  An unhandled error occurred processing a request for the endpoint "authenticateUser".
> In the case of an unhandled error, no tags will be "provided" or "invalidated". [TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of null]

Here is the solution with Fetch API ( works ):

```
const url = 'https://<cannotShowUrl>/Login?redirect=none';

const authenticate = (municipality, profileName, password) => {
  const form = {
    kommune: municipality,
    benutzername: profileName,
    passwort: password,
  };

  const urlencodedForm = Object.keys(form)
    .map((key) => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(form[key])}`)
    .join('&');

  return fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept:
        'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: urlencodedForm,
  })
    .then((response) => response.headers.get('Set-Cookie'))
    .then((cookie) => {
      const ID = cookie.match(/ID=([^;]*)/)?.[1];

      if (!ID)
        throw new Error('Invalid credentials');

      return ID;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(`Error during login: ${error.message}`);
      return error;
    });
};

export { authenticate };
```

I have tried to reimplement the same idea with RTK Query as following ( does not work ):

```
const url = '/Login?redirect=none';
export const loginApiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'loginApiSlice',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'https://<cannotShowUrl>' }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    authenticateUser: builder.mutation({
      query: (credentials) => {
        const form = {
          kommune: credentials.municipality,
          benutzername: credentials.profileName,
          passwort: credentials.password,
        };

        const urlencodedForm = Object.keys(form)
          .map((key) => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(form[key])}`)
          .join('&');

        console.log(urlencodedForm);

        return {
          url,
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            Accept:
              'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          },
          body: urlencodedForm,
        };
      },
      transformResponse: (response) => {
        console.log('response');
        console.log(response);
        const cookie = response.headers.get('Set-Cookie');
        const ID = cookie?.match(/ID=([^;]*)/)?.[1];

        if (!ID) {
          console.log('error');
          throw new Error('Credentials are not valid');
        }

        return ID;
      },
      transformErrorResponse(response, meta, arg) {
        console.log('error');
        console.log(response);
      },
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useAuthenticateUserMutation } = loginApiSlice;
```

Versions of RN and Redux:

```
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
"react-redux": "^8.1.1",
"react-native": "0.71.11",
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What part doesn't work?

Comment: @AmyBlankenship As I have described, solution that I have reimplemented with Redux RTK Query returns null as response.  transformResponse: (response) => { console.log(response).... } prints null as it can be seen in the log that I have also provided. The same solution with Fetch API returns normal response ( not null ) and I can get set-cookie from headers.

Comment: Is `response.headers.get('Set-Cookie')` where the code/logic is failing? What is the result of `console.log({ response });`? What debugging steps have been taken? Have you inspected the network requests? Are you sure your "working" code isn't also throwing the same error and is being caught whereas in the second example it isn't?

Comment: The error is generated from response.headers.get('Set-Cookie'), yes. But the problem comes from the fact the response is NULL. console.log({response}) returns {"response": null}. The network request is fine. As I said, I send the request to the same endpoint from Fetch API with exact same implementation as I have mentioned as well and I get a decent response from which I can retrieve the the cookie. I have also added transformErrorResponse in Redux implementation, but is this block is not entered -> it does not see the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response` in `transformResponse` is the fully parsed data, not the `Response` object you would have access to in `fetch`. It's actually called `baseQueryReturnValue` in the docs.
You want to access the `meta.response` object in the second argument, `meta`.
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries

```js
      transformResponse: (baseQueryReturnValue, meta) => {
        const cookie = meta.response.headers.get('Set-Cookie');
        const ID = cookie?.match(/ID=([^;]*)/)?.[1];

        if (!ID) {
          return null // never throw an error here!
        }

        return ID;
      },
```

Comment: Thank you! Straight to the point and with clearly explained solution! Now everything works :)